# In a Reflexive banach space, given a closed convex set $C$ and some point $y$, there is a point in $C$, of minimal distance to $y$

Tags: functional-analysis

In a Reflexive space, given a closed convex set $C$ and some point $y$, there is a point in $C$, of minimal distance to $y$

All i could figure out is that there is a sequence $z_n \in C$ z.t $\|y-z_n\|\to min distance$ and that $z_n$ converges weakly as it is a bounded sequence. I am not sure where to go from here

Comment: I d.k. But it's not true for Banach spaces in general. If $B$ is a Banach space and $0\ne f\in B^*$ and $C=f^{-1}\{0\}$ then $ C$ is a closed vector-subspace of $B$ with co-dimension $1$, and TFAE: (i)$ \, \forall y\in B\,\exists z\in C\,(\|y-z\|=d(y,C)\,)$, (ii) $\exists y\in B\,\exists z\in C (0\ne f(y)\land \|y-z\|=d(y,C)\,)$ ,(iii) $\exists y\in B\,(0\ne \|f\|\cdot \|y\|=|f(y)|\,).$

Answer (score 2):

A subset $C$ of X which  has the property that for every $x \in X$, the distance $\operatorname{dist}(x,C)$ is attained (i.e there exists a $c \in C$ s.t $||x-c||=\operatorname{dist}(x,C)$) is called proximinal.

We shall show that if $C$ is a closed and bounded subset of a reflexive space $X$, then $C$ is proximinal. Let $x \in X$ and  $d=\operatorname{dist(x,C}):= \inf \{ ||{x-c}|| \colon c \in C\}$. By the definition of the infimum, for all $n \in \mathbb N$, we can find a $ z_n \in B_{d+1/n}(x) \cap C := 
\{ c \in C \colon ||x-c|| \leq d+1/n\}$ (so the intersection is not empty). Define the sequence of subsets  $(A_n)_n \subset 2^X$, by $A_n = B_{d+1/n}(x) \cap C$. Notice that $B_{d+1} \supset A_1 \supset A_2 \supset \dots \ $ and $B_{d+1}$ is weakly compact (since X is reflexive). Furthermore, one can easily check that the famlily $(A_n)_n$ has the finite intersection property and so, we can find a $z \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb N} B_{d+1/n}\cap C$. The point $z$ is the required.

In fact, it can be shown that a normed space X is reflexive if and only if every closed and convex subset of X is proximinal. (The opposite direction is due to James' theorem.)

Comment: Why is the ball $B_{d_+1} $ weakly compact? Don't we just have that $X$ is reflexive if and only if the closed unit ball is weakly compact? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, notice that the closed unit ball is compact if and only if any closed ball of radius $r>0$ is compact. This is thanks to the continuity of the translation maps  $x \mapsto x+a$, for all $a \in X$ (the image of a compact set under a continuous image is compact).

Comment: Why are the $A_n$ closed in the weak topology? $B_{d+1/n}$ is clearly compact hence closed in the weak topology which is Hausdorff. However $C$ is closed only in the $\lVert \cdot \rVert$ topology and not necessarly in the weak topology... If $C$ is convex, we can use geometric Hahn Banach to prove it is closed in the weak topology. Maybe when you write $C$ is bounded you mean $C$ is convex?

Comment: @Kadmos yes, it's a typo. $C$ is assumed to be convex

Answer (score 1):

You are on the right track. Since $C$ is not only closed but also convex, it is weakly closed. The weak limit of the sequence $(z_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, lets call it $z$, therefore satisfies $z \in C$. Can you show that $z$ indeed minimizes the distance using that the norm is (sequentially) weakly lower semi-continuous?